# Trying to get Git to work. Downloads a different code set than on git

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Have a couple questions as me and most my cowokers are used to TFS and run into trouble most every step with GIT.

First off. I have a branch I am trying to get.

It was checked in at the office and trying to get it at home.

Sync fails no matter what I do as usual.
So deleted the local project folder and opened project from source control. The problem is, what I got is not what's shown in the online git.

It's an older version.

Do I have to do something special to get my branch?

I am going to the project and selecting my branch copying the url given. Noticed the URL doesn't change when I change branches. Even at this step, I get the regular error that there are uncommitted changes.
I didn't change anything, just got the project.

Also have the desktop github installed. At the office before I left, it showed all my changes. Yet at home, it only shows an old version. What is the desktop app supposed to be used for? Makes no sense to my why a repository should show differently.

Read a couple tutorials and none seem to actually work for any of us.

I guess in short, what do I need to do to be able to check in code to a branch at the office and get that same code base at home without spending a bunch of time deleting projects and fighting with this?

1 more piece. Why would it be that I delete everything, clone in desktop and I get the error NuGet packages are missing? Why isn't it downloading all the code? Or is this just another step I am missing to get all the code?

Using VS 2015 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple possible issues you might be running into, but I can't tell completely what you have and haven't done.

First thing would be, did you only clone the repository, without switching to the branch you want? When you clone, you will check out the default branch by default. If the default branch doesn't match with the online default branch, I'm not sure what the issue is.

The other thing I can think of, you said "checked in". In Git, you need to stage your changes, commit them, then push them to your remote repository. Have you done all of this?

Uncommitted changes on a fresh clone is generally caused by things like line endings, which is a settings issue normally. You won't be able to pull new content (or checkout a branch) properly if you get that error, so your best bet there is either to just commit those "changes", or fix whatever is causing the discrepancy. There's probably another option, but I can't specifically remember it at the moment.

Comment: I don't see any way to clone a specific branch without using the command shell. Is that correct? Not sure what you mean by stage changes. Used to choosing checkin, type a description and done. Quick search talks about it when using the shell. It sounds like you are saying the GitHub desktop app and the VS git interface are basically worthless and just to use the shell for anything to work right. Lastly, committing the changes and doing a sync, I'm right back to the same situation. Even tried excluding the suo files in the github app, but that apparently does nothing.

Comment: Also, I did just delete everything locally. Did a shell git clone -b branchname url and I still get an old version of code from 3 days ago. Is there something else besides the project folder I need to delete to be able to get a recent copy locally?